# CompletableFuture.get not waiting for final block

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, java-11, completable-future

I have a custom ExecutorService,

```
class CustomExecutorService implements ExecutorService {

        ExecutorService delegate;

        public CustomExecutorService(ExecutorService delegate){
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }
        // All methods are just delegated to the delegate except execute
        
        public void execute(Runnable command) {
            this.delegate.execute(wrapRunnable(command));
        }

        private Runnable wrapRunnable(final Runnable command) {
            return () -> {
                try {
                    command.run();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Finalizer done.");
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Now this is my test code,

```
ExecutorService executorService = new CustomExecutorService(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> System.out.println("Command done."), executorService).get();
System.out.println("Main Thread Done.");
```

Now I expect the following output to happen,

```
Command done.
Finalizer done. //After a wait of 2 seconds
Main Thread Done.
```

However what is happening is,

```
Command done.
Main Thread Done.
```

And it is not even waiting for the `finally` block and main thread is exiting. I am not able to explain this behaviour as `CompletableFuture#get` is supposed to be blocking, but it seems it is not waiting for the `finallly` block.

I am aware that `finally` is not guaranteed to be executed if the `finally` is going to be executed by a daemon thread and all other non-daemon threads exit before `finally` is called. However ExecutorService threads are non-daemon threads, so `finally` should be executed.

I am running this on `corretto-11.0.11`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run `CompletableFuture.runAsync` it wraps your `Runnable` in a task (`AsyncRun` in the source) which runs the runnable, then marks the CompletableFuture as complete. This is what's passed to the executor.

In your executor you are wrapping *that* task so the future is already marked complete by the time your `finally` block runs, which is why `get()` returns immediately after that point.

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question, perhaps it's just high-level and I'm not managing to understand the details. 1. How can the OP resolve the problem? 2. Why is `CompletableFuture.runAsync` completing the future before `executorService` actually finishes running it?

Comment: 1. The OP needs to wrap the Runnable at another level to achieve this result; what they're trying to do is not possible, but they only requested an explanation :). 2. A `CompletableFuture` is a future which returns _when it is marked complete_. Processing can continue after that point. By intercepting at the `Executor` level the requester is effectively bypassing the `CompletableFuture` "layer" so it's not reasonable to expect the higher-level API to work well. It's definitely confusing though!

Comment: More directly doing `yourFuture.whenCompleteAsync( () -> { Thread.sleep(2000); ... etc. } ).get();` would achieve the goal of waiting after the initial value completed, but you can't do that at the lower level of the executor.

Comment: This was just a mcve, the actual `finally` block does not sleep but runs something which I was verifying post doing a get on the future and the verification was failing.
I accepted this because it clearly explains *why* this is happening, which was what I wanted.

Comment: @AdwaitKumar try replacing `this.delegate.execute(wrapRunnable(command));` with `wrapRunnable(command).run();`, the code will run as you expect. Problem is not that the runnable is wrapped, but because you're delegating to `delegate.execute`, which is running asynchronously. Not saying that it's wrong to accept the answer, but just checking that the answer actually points to the main cause.

Comment: I want to run the code asynchronously, otherwise it would execute on the caller thread, which defeats the purpose an ExecutorService.

Comment: @AdwaitKumar That's right. I thought the problem was that blocking on the completable future was futile...?

Answer (score 2):

Look the source code of `CompletableFuture` at Line 1627(Jdk 1.8) as shows below:

```
public void run() {
    CompletableFuture<Void> d; Runnable f;
        if ((d = dep) != null && (f = fn) != null) {
            dep = null; fn = null;
            if (d.result == null) {
                try {
                    f.run();
                    d.completeNull(); // line 1627
                } catch (Throwable ex) {
                    d.completeThrowable(ex);
                }
            }
            d.postComplete();
        }
    }
}
```

When the `Runnable f` is done, CompletableFuture's result will be set to `null`, then the `get()` method will not be bloked anymore. And in your case `Runnable f` is equal to `System.out.println("Command done.")`

You can set a breakpoint at the entry of `CompletableFuture runAsync(Runnable runnable, Executor executor)` and debug step by step, you will find when the result of CompletableFuture is set.